# Restore PDF to Evernote service in Lion

Tags: pdf, printing

Anyone knows how to restore the print PDF to Evernote in Lion 10.7.2?

Comment: I am running 10.7.2 and Evernote 3.0.5. I still have all of the PDF options including to print any note to PDF. Can you provide more details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a commonly discussed issue on the Evernote message boards when Lion debuted.  I've seen all sorts of "fixes" including hacking an old version of Evernote.  Fortunately, there's a much easier option.

1. Print something
2. Choose "Edit Menu..." from the PDF menu in the Print dialog
3. Click the "+" button then navigate to Evernote, highlight it and click "Choose"
4. You will now have an option called "Evernote" in the PDF menu in all of your system print dialogs.  Choosing this option will print to pdf, and open that pdf in a new note in Evernote.

This process has been tested on 10.7.2 with Evernote 3.0.5.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: No problem.  Glad to help.